# C# Generics : how to use x.MaxValue / x.MinValue (int, float, double) in a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, floating-point, int, double

I'm using the WPF Extended Toolkit ( http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/ ).

It has a nice NumericUpDown control that I'd like to use, but internally it uses doubles - which means it uses double.MinValue and double.MaxValue.

I'd like to use the same control, but I need a generic version - for ints it needs to use int.MaxValue/MinValue, for floats float.MaxValue/MinValue, etc. (I think you get the idea :))

So I though about copying the NumericUpDown to a GNumericUpDown, where T would ofcourse be the Type..
But this doesn't work, because a generic Type doesn't have MinValue / MaxValue.
And normally I'd use the 'where' clause to specify a base-type, but this doesn't work as afaik there's no common interface that defines 'MinValue' and 'MaxValue'.

Is there a way to solve this with generics, or do I really need to copy/paste/search&replace the original NumericUpDown for each type ?

Comment: Your bigger concern is going to be how to do arithmetic with a generic type... see [Marc Gravell's work with Expression Trees for that](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The OP made this comment on another answer:

> I want to use these controls in my
>   XAML. My idea was to create a generic
>   version, and then create empty classes
>   like NumericUpDownInt :
>   GNumericUpDown { } Would that be
>   the way to go, or is there a
>   better/cleaner way to your knowledge

If you're going to go that route, then just pass the min and max directly:

```
class abstract GenericNumericUpDown<T>
{
    public GenericNumericUpDown(T min, T max) { ... }
}

class NumericUpDownInt : GenericNumericUpDown<int>
{
    public NumericUpDownInt() : base(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue) { ... }
}

class NumericUpDownFloat : GenericNumericUpDown<float>
{
    public NumericUpDownFloat() : base(float.MinValue, float.MaxValue) { ... }
}

class NumericUpDownDouble : GenericNumericUpDown<double>
{
    public NumericUpDownDouble() : base(double.MinValue, double.MaxValue) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Well, ofcourse. I'm shocked as why this didn't occur to me. I figure it's one of those cases of thinking too complex so I've missed the simple solution.

Answer (score 11):

Well, given that you can get at the type at execution time, you *could* rely on the fact that all of the numeric types in .NET have `MinValue` and `MaxValue` fields, and read them with reflection. It wouldn't be terribly nice, but easy enough to do:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

// Use constraints which at least make it *slightly* hard to use
// with the wrong types...
public class NumericUpDown<T> where T : struct,
    IComparable<T>, IEquatable<T>, IConvertible
{
    public static readonly T MaxValue = ReadStaticField("MaxValue");
    public static readonly T MinValue = ReadStaticField("MinValue");

    private static T ReadStaticField(string name)
    {
        FieldInfo field = typeof(T).GetField(name,
            BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
        if (field == null)
        {
            // There's no TypeArgumentException, unfortunately. You might want
            // to create one :)
            throw new InvalidOperationException
                ("Invalid type argument for NumericUpDown<T>: " +
                 typeof(T).Name);
        }
        return (T) field.GetValue(null);
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(NumericUpDown<int>.MaxValue); 
        Console.WriteLine(NumericUpDown<float>.MinValue);
    }
}
```

Note that if you use this with an inappropriate type, I've tried to force a compile-time error as best I can... but it won't be foolproof. If you manage to find a structure with all the right interfaces but without `MinValue` and `MaxValue` fields, then any attempt to use the `NumericUpDown` with that type will cause an exception to be thrown.

Comment: Sample would be extremely appreciated ! :) By the way, Jon, judging by your responsetime - are you superhuman by any chance ? You first of all seem to know maybe not everything, but something close to it - and you always seem to be there when someone like me is in trouble :) Cheers :)

Comment: @IUsedToBeAPygmy: You were just lucky :) I think I'm about to go off-net for the night...

Comment: Jon - first of all, thanks for the brilliant input - haven't tested it yet, but even if it wouldn't compile you've given me a completely new direction to think about :)
But just while I have your attention ;) - I want to use these controls in my XAML. My idea was to create a generic version, and then create empty classes like NumericUpDownInt : GNumericUpDown<int> { } Would that be the way to go, or is there a better/cleaner way to your knowledge ?

Comment: @IUsedToBeAPygmy: I'm afraid I've no idea how well generics and XAML mix. You *may* find it convenient to have a generic base class, but then subtypes of `DecimalUpDown`, `Int32UpDown` etc solely to make the XAML simpler. Worth thinking about as a backup plan :) (EDIT: Ah, I see you edited your comment to suggest pretty much the same thing... so at the very least, you're as crazy as I am or vice versa :)

Comment: @Jon - Cheers, you're a hero :) Sleep tight :)
Edit: Crazyness is relative.
My dayjob is PS3 games, the hacks in that code are beyond imagination ;)

Comment: Since there are only a few numeric types and that number will never change, it might just be better to use as-expressions and if-statements instead of slower reflection.  It'd also be more clear, codewise.

Comment: @siride: The reflection here will only ever be carried out once per type - and given the number of possible types involved (9, discounting byte and sbyte) I'd say that the code using `as` (or whatever) would be considerably less clear.

Comment: Also to consider that if he is going to just do subtypes of whatever possibility he is going to have, then is going to be easier just to provide the max/min number à la strategy. I like Jon's method anyway, no need to be afraid of reflection.. it's a shame that the dynamic keyword doesn't work with static members!

Comment: @Sebastian: Providing it as a strategy pattern has pros and cons. In particular, it's handy if you want to be able to vary the min/max by *instance* of the type... but on the other hand, if you want to be able to use `MaxValue` and `MinValue` from logically static methods, it's a pain if they have to be instance methods just to get at a value which won't *really* vary by instance :(

Comment: @Jon : I'm implementing a version like your suggestion.

Now I encounter a single spot where a conversion is done like : 

double val = Convert.ToDouble(value);
(Where value is an object)

Would there be a way to do a generic convert ?

T val = Convert.[Insert Some Magic Here to convert to T](value)

Comment: see Convert.ChangeType method

Comment: @IUsedToBeAPygmy: What's the actual type of the value?

Comment: Regarding performance, if its an issue you could use dynamic code generation to compile real code that can be executed instead of using reflection.

Comment: @BurningIce: I guarantee that the reflection used in this code will *not* be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @everyone : it's a usercontrol. Which means it's not going to be my performance-bottleneck; the user is only so fast ;)
The bottleneck will be the enormous amount of rendering I'll do on the GPU, not the usercontrol that will control a single render-parameter ;)
But really, thanks for all your input, I really appreciate your reactions.

Comment: @Sebastian : Thank you very much, exactly what I needed. Excuse me for not RTFM'ing ;)

Comment: @jon i know... it was more as an input for how it ALSO could be done, just so we have all the possibilities; reflection, switch case, as casting and dynamic code generation :)

Answer (score 3):

You should get the latest source code for the Extended WPF Toolkit.  The updated NumericUpDown control allows you to specify what data type to use in the editor.  The following code specifies to use an Int32 as the data type instead of the default double.  As you can see this is done by setting the ValueType property on the NumericUpDown control.

```
<extToolkit:NumericUpDown Grid.Row="1" Value="{Binding Age}" Increment="1" Minimum="18" Maximum="65" ValueType="{x:Type sys:Int32}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is also useful in Testing scenarios:

You may use extension methods, such that in C#6 (introducing `nameof`) you could write:

```
public static class TypeExtension
{
    public static T MinValue<T>(this Type self)
    {
        return (T)self.GetField(nameof(MinValue)).GetRawConstantValue();
    }

    public static T MaxValue<T>(this Type self)
    {
        return (T)self.GetField(nameof(MaxValue)).GetRawConstantValue();
    }

}
```

and invoke through some admittedly ugly syntax:

```
var intMinValue = typeof(int).MinValue<int>();
```

which in your generic method would be

```
var typeMinValue = typeof(T).MinValue<T>();
```

*Note, that I am not certain that all primitive types declare their Min/Max values as constants. Use `GetValue` instead.*

Comment: just a sidenote: misleading here may be that `nameof(MinValue)` references the method you are defining - and not an eventual `MinValue` property of `Type self` - so its not really better (if at all!) than using `"MinValue"` explicitly.