# How can I make this simple method into a generic method?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, comparison-operators

I have a method as follows:

```
int coerce(int val, int min=0, int max = 10)
{
    if (val < min)
        return min;
    if (val > max)
        return max;
    return val;
}
```

Now, I have to make it for `byte`, `float`, `double`, and other numeric types.

As all we know, making numerous similar methods for those types is very ineffective, so I want to make it into a generic method.  The following is the what I tried to do:

```
T coerce<T>(T val, T min=(T)0, T max=(T)10) where T:IComparable
{
    // ... same as the above ...
}
```

I know that the code does not run, and that's why I'm asking for this.  I'm currently confused by two questions:

1. How can I compare `T` types?

   Visual Studio warns about the operator `<` and `>`.  I tried to use `where T:IComparable` but it did not solve my problem.
2. How can I set default values for a generic argument?

   I tried to use `(T)0` and `(T)10` for it.  But it was not a good choice, anyway.

It may be a simple question, but I couldn't find answer from Google.

Comment: Did you look at the msdn example ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `IComparable` defines `CompareTo`, not the comparison operators. So instead of `val < min` for instance, you need to use `val.CompareTo(min) == -1`

Comment: ... and you cannot use `int` default values for your generic implementation, the best you could do is `int min = default` but IMO you should not try to implement default values in this method.

Comment: How can I set default values for generic type argument? - You can use the `Default(T)` which sets it to the default value of the datatype. In your case 0 for integer.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, now Q1 is very clear to me. 
But for Q2, default value of the variable 'min' may not be 0. So I can't use ```Default(T)```.

Comment: Guys, for Q2, I have an idea to solve the  problem.

```T coerce<T>(T val, T? min, T? max) where T:struct```

And now I just check ```min == null``` and ```max == null```.

But I can't assign default value such as ```if(min == null) max = (T)10```.

Any ideas to solve this last problem?

Comment: I think [`Clamp()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_(graphics)), not `coerce()`, would be a more appropriate and well-known name for this method.  With that in mind, many of the answers to [Where can I find the “clamp” function in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2683442/150605) provide a generic implementation of this.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, @BACON ! Actually, I'm not a native English speaker. So these kinds of tips are so valuable for me. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`Compare`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable-1.compareto?view=netframework-4.8) method instead of `<` or `>` operators. And apply the correct generic constraints, for numeric types it should be `IComparable, IComparable<T>, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>, IFormattable`. However, you can leave only `where T : struct, IComparable<T>`, it should be enough for your purposes (but `struct` is important here, since you are comparing value types)

```cs
T coerce<T>(T val, T min, T max) where T : struct, IComparable, IComparable<T>, IConvertible, IEquatable<T>, IFormattable
{
    if (val.CompareTo(min) < 0)
        return min;
    if (val.CompareTo(max) > 0)
        return max;

    return val;
}
```

You can also specify the default `min` value like `T min = default(T)`, but you can't do that for `max` value.

Following the comments, in case of using `Nullable<T>` for `min` and `max` values the code can be written like

```cs
T coerce<T>(T val, T? min = default, T? max = default) where T : struct, IComparable<T>
{
    var minValue = min.HasValue ? min.Value : default(T);
    var maxValue = max.HasValue ? max.Value : (T)Convert.ChangeType(10, typeof(T));

    if (val.CompareTo(minValue) < 0)
        return minValue;
    if (val.CompareTo(minValue) > 0)
        return maxValue;

    return val;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your help. Q1 is very clear now for me. 
But still, Q2 is a problem.. ```min``` could not be 0, so I can't use default(T)
The code above is just a simplified example of mine.
Anyway, thanks for the help!!

Comment: @J.-H.Bak you can use a reflection to get and `Min` and `Max` values of `T`, it's explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4418645/4728685), But it looks like an overkill here, IMO. Specifying a explicit values directly is more clear and readble

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I agree with that it is a waste. Here I bring a new idea for assigning default value for input parameters. But still need one step. Can I ask for just one more help to complete this idea?

```T coerce<T>(T val, T? min, T? max) where T:struct ``` and then ```if(max == null) max = (T)10```. But now I can't assign the value for it.

Comment: @J.-H.Bak `T` can be any numeric value, not only the `int`, so `max = (T)10` isn't valid, unfortunately. You may use `Convert.ChangeType` for that. In case of nullable `T` you'll need to access the `Value` property of it

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public T Max<T>(T val, T min, T max) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    if (val.CompareTo(min) == -1)
        return min;

    if (val.CompareTo(min) == 1)
        return max;

    return val;
}
```

[Detail](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2015/05/make-generic-min-and-max-methods-in-c/)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help. :) 
Now I realize that I completely misunderstood ```IComparable``` thing.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is use the IComparable methods, not the compare operators. In this case the [CompareTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto?view=netframework-4.8) method

Default values for parameters is not easy, you are supposing numeric values and doing direct cast, but thing that T can be any IComparable data type

```
public static T Coerce<T>(T val, T min, T max) where T:IComparable {
    if (val.CompareTo(min) < 0)
        return min;
    else if (val.CompareTo(max) > 0)
        return max;
    else
        return val;
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fJUDdR

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer and sharing your time for this. This helps me a lot!