# Trying to print type proterties with a foreach loop (C#)

Tags: c#, types

I'm working on a simple console application. I want the application to print out a table showing the MinValue and MaxValue of different numeric types.

I have one Console.WriteLine statement that prints out the heading of the table.

After this I want a single line printed for each type (with name of type, MinValue and Maxvalue as columns). I could of course do this with one WriteLine statement for each type, e.g. for sbyte: typeof(sbyte).Name, sbyte.MinValue, sbyte.MinValue.But I thought I would try to solve it with a foreach loop.

Here's my current code:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>()
        {
            typeof(sbyte),
            typeof(byte),
            typeof(short),
            typeof(ushort),
            typeof(int),
            typeof(uint),
            typeof(long),
            typeof(ulong),
            typeof(float),
            typeof(double),
            typeof(decimal)
        };

        // Heading
        Console.WriteLine(
            format: "{0,-8} {1,6:N0} {2, 12:N0}",
            arg0: "Type",
            arg1: "Min",
            arg2: "Max");

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                format: "{0,-8} {1,6:N0} {2, 12:N0}",
                arg0: type.Name,
                arg1: type.MinValue,
                arg2: type.MaxValue);
        }
```

This works for the Name property, but not for MinValue and MaxValue, which throw an error: (MinValue example:) "'Type' does not contain a definition for 'MinValue' and no accessible extension method 'MinValue' accepting a first argument of type 'Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I thought this would work as all of the types in my list have Min/MaxValue properties.

I've also tried with a list of strings (names of the types stored as strings), which obviously did not work.

1) Is the problem that I am trying to use a variable as a type?

2) And why is this not a problem with the Name property?

3) Is there a way to get around this, and still use a foreach loop?

Comment: 2) Because `Type` has a `Name` property.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418636/c-sharp-generics-how-to-use-x-maxvalue-x-minvalue-int-float-double-in-a) is how to get MinValue and MaxValue for a generic type.